# Turnaround Time excluding Weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hi i need to get the turnaround time of this columns excluding the weekends. I tried to subtract it but without the excluding the weekends, so i am not successful to get the right turnaround time needed. Please help me to get the right formula for excluding the weekends of this sample. Thanks

[image] 
As you can see here, this is the data that i need to get the TURNAROUND TIME, so what i did is column N subtract to column M.

[image]
This is the formula i used to see the results with correct format but i want to have a result which will have a exclusion of weekends but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your formula can be shrunk to `=TEXT(N2-M2, "d"" days ""h"" hours ""m"" minutes""")` - or, just set the Number Format (Right click & "Format Cells" or just [Ctrl]+[1]) to `d" days "h" hours "m" minutes";@` to leave the value as a number but *display* it as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comments in the old answer have grown - to the extent that **the question needs editing** to include all of the "additional" requirements (and there are [various reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal) why these [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are often frowned upon.  For any more "tweaks", raise a new question.) - I am posting the updated code here.

First: Since `NETWORKDAYS` counts from the Start of the first day to the End of the Last day, it tends to add an "extra" day.  To fix this, we need to remember to subtract the first-part of the first day (midnight to start time) and the last part of the last day (end time to midnight) - but only if they are each Workdays.

```java
=NETWORKDAYS(M2,N2)+IF(MOD(WEEKDAY(N2),7)>1,MOD(N2,1)-1,0)-IF(MOD(WEEKDAY(M2),7)>1,MOD(M2,1),0)
```

Next, was the requirement to exclude Holidays.  **IMPORTANT!** This requires that you have a Worksheet called "Holiday Sheet", with a list of the Dates of your Holidays in Column A.
*We use `ISERROR(MATCH(..))` as a check for "Not in the list", and `NETWORKDAYS` accepts the list the third, optional, argument/parameter*

```java
=NETWORKDAYS(M2,N2,'Holiday Sheet'!$A:$A)+IF(AND(MOD(WEEKDAY(N2),7)>1,ISERROR(MATCH(N2,'Holiday Sheet'!$A:$A,0))),MOD(N2,1)-1,0)-IF(AND(MOD(WEEKDAY(M2),7)>1,ISERROR(MATCH(M2,'Holiday Sheet'!$A:$A,0))),MOD(M2,1),0)
```

The last "extra" requirement was to calculate this as Working Hours, with a workday running from 07:00 to 16:00 - a 9 hour day.  To start, multiply `NETWORKDAYS` by 9 hours (`TIME(9,0,0)`), and then remember to remove the first-part of the first day (corrected for working hours) and the last part of the last day (also corrected for working hours).
*We can use `MEDIAN` to get the middle number from 3 values, so that we never use a time before 07:00 or after 16:00*

```java
=TIME(9,0,0)*NETWORKDAYS(M2,N2,'Holiday Sheet'!$A:$A)+IF(AND(MOD(WEEKDAY(N2),7)>1,ISERROR(MATCH(N2,'Holiday Sheet'!$A:$A,0))),MEDIAN(TIME(7,0,0),MOD(N2,1),TIME(16,0,0))-TIME(16,0,0),0)-IF(AND(MOD(WEEKDAY(M2),7)>1,ISERROR(MATCH(N2,'Holiday Sheet'!$A:$A,0))),MEDIAN(TIME(7,0,0),MOD(M2,1),TIME(16,0,0))-TIME(7,0,0),0)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using the following formula, this will calculate the Work Days between two dates:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(N2,M2)
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account that if start or end date is a weekend day they need to be subtracted on an minute base as this is his smallest unit.

Comment: To fix the missing part-days try this: `=NETWORKDAYS(M2,N2)+IF(MOD(WEEKDAY(N2),7)>1,MOD(N2,1)-1,0)-IF(MOD(WEEKDAY(M2),7)>1,MOD(M2,1),0)`

Comment: @Chronocidal Nice short solution!

Comment: For the OP's reference:  `NETWORKDAYS` measures from the *start* of the first workday to the *end* of the last workday - so, for the same date twice it gives `1` for a workday or `0` for a non workday.  This means we need to subtract the first-part of the first day (midnight to start time) and the last part of the last day (end time to midnight) - but *only* if they are each Workdays.

Comment: How about if i need to add cut off time and holidays @Chronocidal. Example of cut off time is 7:00 am - 4:00 pm.

Comment: @airctirtap Does the cutoff time apply just to the start/end of the first/last day, or to all days (i.e. Monday 02:00 to 20:00 is 9 hours (07:00 to 16:00), but is Monday-noon to Tuesday-noon 24 hours (1 day) or 9 hours (`12:00 to 16:00` = 4 hours + `07:00 to 12:00` = 5 hours))?

Comment: @aicirtap If you have a column with your holidays in, `NETWORKDAYS` will accept that as the optional third argument - .e.g `=NETWORKDAYS(Date(2018,4,23), Date(2018,4,27),Date(2018,4,25))` will be 4 - Weekdays from 23rd April (Monday) to 27th April (Friday) excluding 25th April (Wednesday) as a holiday.  Your `IF` statements will then need to use `MATCH` to check if the first and last days are holidays (i.e. `-IF(AND(MOD(WEEKDAY(M2),7)>1,ISERROR(MATCH(Int(M2),'Holiday Sheet'!$A:$A,0))),MOD(M2,1),0)` will check a list of holiday dates in Column A of the worksheet "Holiday Sheet"

Comment: @Chronocidal it will apply to all the days. Thanks

Comment: How will i add cut off time to this formula that you have given?

Comment: @aircirtap to add to the "complete" days, multiply the `NETWORKTIME(..)` by `TIME(9,0,0)` to make it 9-hour-days.  To add it to the Part-days, you'll want to use `MIN` and `MAX` to ensure that the start/end time is within one bound, and subtract from the other instead of 00:00 or 24:00 -   i.e. `,MOD(M2,1),0` becomes `MIN(MOD(M2,1),TIME(16,0,0))-TIME(7,0,0),0` as the last day starts at 07:00 and ends by 16:00 at the latest

Comment: You'll probably want to change your TextFormat to `[h]" hours "m" minutes";@` so that 1.5 days shows as "36 hours" instead of "1 day 12 hours" too if you're not actually working in days

Comment: @Chronocidal how about if it will just apply just to the start/end of the first/last day? can you give me the sample formula for this?

Comment: @Chronocidal your example above regarding the cut off time is what i am looking for, can you please help me for the formula of it? complete days cut off is not working properly because i am having a result more than the needed turn around time.